# Where are list_text conversions stored?

Tags: database, nodes

I have a field in a content type that is a list_text with a key/value pair where the key is stored in the database and the value is the text visible in the drop down menu.

I imported a large amount of data.  When I look at the data in a view or view a node, the key shows up.  However, after I edit the node, whether I've made changes or not, the value starts appearing in the view and in the node.  I would like this to be the case for every node, but can't possibly go though and manually edit each node.

Can anyone tell me where in the database the info that tells Drupal to use the translate the key to its value is stored?

Answer (score 0):

The [Field CRUD API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/group/field_crud/7) could be a better approach instead of handmade DB calls.

If you must: Field creats two DB tables for every field they are called field_data_field_fieldname and field_revision_fieldname. The contents depends on the field type.

Comment: I will look into the Field CRUD API. As far as the db is concerned, field_data_field_fieldname->field_fieldname_value ALL show the key value, both for records that end up in Views showing the value as well as records that show the key. The question is, how is the info as to whether or not to use the key vs the value stored in the db? I have combed through the db to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean where the translations are stored, the tables are

locales_source
locales_target